# can i connect to my php file using my jQuery AJAX post method's data key?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have been trying to connect a user submitted comma seperated string to a php file that would do various calculations through a Javascript function that is called on click.
starting from my html page

```
  <div class="button-holder">
        <?php if(!$voted):?>
      <a href="" onclick="javascript:submitvote('voteIFC');"   class="button">Submit Poll<span></span></a><?php endif;?>
 </div>
```

once it is clicked i was trying to use the ajax post method to asynchronously connect to the php if conditional and enter it into a database

```
    function submitvote(uv){
     document.getElementById('rank_ul').innerHTML='<img src="ajax-loader.gif">';
   var uv= $('ul.sort').sortable('toArray').join(',');
   var url= "results.php";
  $.post(url,
   {userOrder:uv},
   function(data){
   document.getElementById('rank_ul').innerHTML= 'return_data'
   });

    };
```

but i cant seem to figure out how to connect this ajax function (whos purpose is to collect the order of a sortable) and send it to a php file for further calculations and database entries. i tried a lot of different things but read that you could connect the $.Post to an if conditional by referring to the $.post 's data key (called 'userOrder' )like so

```
 <?php

   if(!defined('INCLUDE_CHECK')) die('You are not allowed to execute this    file directly');

  // If the poll has been submitted:
  $userOrder= $_POST['userOrder'];


if($userOrder=='voteIFC'){


// The data arrives as a comma-separated string,
// so we extract each post ids:
$data=explode(',',str_replace('li','',$_POST['sortdata']));

// Getting the number of objects
list($tot_objects) = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sort_objects"));

if(count($data)!=$tot_objects) die("Wrong data!");

foreach($data as $k=>$v)
{
    // Building the sql query:
    $str[]='('.(int)$v.','.($tot_objects-$k).')';
}

$str = 'VALUES'.join(',',$str);

// This will limit voting to once a day per IP:
mysql_query("   INSERT INTO `sort_votes` (ip,date_submit,dt_submit)
                VALUES ('".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',NOW(),NOW())");

//  If the user has not voted before today:
if(mysql_affected_rows($link)==1)
{
    mysql_query('   INSERT INTO `sort_objects` (id,votes) '.$str.'
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE votes = votes+VALUES(votes)');
}

}
```

is using the $.post 's data key not a viable option for passing data through to the PHP if conditional? 
again thank you all so much for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending `sortdata` and overwriting `userOrder` with sort data because the parameter `uv` in `sortData` function is declared and initialized again. Therefore `if($userOrder=='voteIFC') {}` is not executed in PHP.

Try the following code:

```
function submitvote(uv){
     document.getElementById('rank_ul').innerHTML='<img src="ajax-loader.gif">';
     var sortdata = $('ul.sort').sortable('toArray').join(',');
     var url= "results.php";
     $.post(url, {userOrder:uv, sortdata: sortdata}, function(data){
         document.getElementById('rank_ul').innerHTML= 'return_data'
     });
}
```

also consider appending `li` to the selector:

```
var sortdata = $('ul.sort li').sortable('toArray').join(',');
```

With this update, you don't have to remove `li` tags at php.